# Issue compiling with Boost 1.56.0

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I'm experiencing a problem. This is related to boost::filesystem. I'm getting this error:
`error: ‘class boost::filesystem::directory_entry’ has no member named ‘filename’`. Have they deprecated it or what?
The code is: `string FileName = i->filename( );`

Comment: Nope, it's [there](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-filename).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filename()` is a member of `path`, not `directory_entry`.

Just do

```
std::string FileName = i->path().filename();
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b2fe17a12f9b52f)**

Comment: Since which boost version it got moved to path()? :)

Comment: @Duosora The **[library homepage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem)** has a large banner saying _"This is Version 3 of the Filesystem library. Version 2 is not longer supported. 1.49.0 was the last release of Boost to supply Version 2"_. I presume that answers it

Comment: Yes, it does. I did some mass injections of replacements and it compiled just fine. Much thanks for explanation. Pardon me for not paying attention on it.